# Where does macOS keep track of signed zips

Tags: macos, zip, sign, signing

I am on macOS and signed a zip file but its SHA256 checksum does not change. Where does macOS track this signing process? Thanks a lot!

```
$ codesign -dvvvv foo.zip 
foo.zip: code object is not signed at all

$ openssl dgst -sha256 foo.zip 
SHA256(foo.zip)= 30b954e18296f858e40f7bdeebb554cbef59e3f1e6ba947bda89c6342687e431

$ codesign --force --timestamp --sign "..." foo.zip 

$ openssl dgst -sha256 foo.zip 
SHA256(foo.zip)=30b954e18296f858e40f7bdeebb554cbef59e3f1e6ba947bda89c6342687e431

$ codesign -dvvvv foo.zip 
// output of signature
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For "generic" files (those in formats that don't support embedded signatures, like Mach-O binaries or disk images), `codesign` will attach the code signature in the form of extended attributes:

```
$ codesign --force --timestamp --sign "..." sub.zip
$ ls -l@ sub.zip 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 gordon  staff  12449 Jul 12 22:36 sub.zip
    com.apple.cs.CodeDirectory    127 
    com.apple.cs.CodeRequirements     164 
    com.apple.cs.CodeRequirements-1   163 
    com.apple.cs.CodeSignature   9012
```

The numbers there are the number of bytes of data in each of the extended attributes. You can view them in more detail with the `xattr` command.